# Insert an element with multiple attributes from Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'd like to add this line to my xml file under system.web tag

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" validation="SHA1" />
```

XML File:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024000" executionTimeout="600" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
        <pages smartNavigation="false" validateRequest="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
        <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/Redirect.aspx" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
        <authorization>
          <allow users="" />
        </authorization>
        <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="25" pageOutput="true" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
        <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />
        <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
        <httpHandlers>
          <add verb="*" path="Compare.aspx" type="kCura.EDDS.WebAPI.Compare, kCura.EDDS.WebAPI" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <webServices>
          <protocols>
            <add name="HttpPost" />
            <remove name="HttpGet" />
            <remove name="Documentation" />
          </protocols>
        </webServices>
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Was able to add a single attribute using these steps:

```
$ChildElement = $xmlDoc.CreateElement('machineKey');
$ChildElement.SetAttribute('decryption','False')
$xmlDoc.configuration.'system.web'.InsertBefore($ChildElement,$xmlDoc.configuration.'system.web'.authentication)
$xmlDoc.Save($fileName)
```

Comment: Are you encountering a problem? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `SetAttribute()` twice, once for each attribute.

```
if($xmldoc.configuration.'system.web'.SelectSingleNode("machineKey") -eq $null) {
    $ChildElement = $xmlDoc.CreateElement('machineKey');
    $ChildElement.SetAttribute('decryption','AES')
    $ChildElement.SetAttribute('validation','SHA1')
    $xmlDoc.configuration.'system.web'.InsertBefore($ChildElement,$xmlDoc.configuration.'system.web'.authentication)
}

$xmlDoc.Save($fileName)
```

Which adds this node:

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" validation="SHA1" />
```

Comment: Config file had some issues saving from that particular location. Works. Thanks. Quick question how do we check if the particular node exists and add when it doesn't exist. Use foreach?

Comment: `if($xmldoc.'system.web'.SelectSingleNode("machineKey") -eq $null) { #element missing, add it }`. Btw. are you sure you don't want to add it before `authorization`? `authentication` isn't an element in the xml, so it will be added to the end of the `system.web` node

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I made that change to authorization. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's stopping you from calling `SetAttribute()` more than once:

```
$ChildElement.SetAttribute('decryption','False')
$ChildElement.SetAttribute('validation','SHA1')
```